# Filter array and show results in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to filter my results via button onClicks in React, but for some reason its not working?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-x7tlxr?file=src/App.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {

  const [fetchData, setFetchData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';

  useEffect(() => {
      let mounted = true;
      const loadData = async () => {
          try {
              const response = await axios(url);
              if (mounted) {
                  setFetchData(response.data);
                  setLoading(false);
                  setIsError(false);
                  console.log('data mounted')
              }
          } catch (err) {
              setIsError(true)
              setLoading(false);
              setFetchData([]);
              console.log(err);
          }
      };
      loadData();
      return () => {
          mounted = false;
          console.log('cleaned');
      };
  },
      [url]
  );
  

  const renderdata = () => {
    if (fetchData) {
      return (
        <div>{fetchData.map(inner => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={inner.id}>
            <p>{inner.title}</p>
            </React.Fragment>
          )
        })}</div>
      )
    } else {
      <p>No data to display!</p>
    }
  }

  const handle1 = () => {
    const result1 = fetchData.filter((inner) => inner.id === '1');
    setFetchData(result1);
  }

  const handle2 = () => {
    const result2 = fetchData.filter((inner) => inner.id === '2');
    setFetchData(result2);
  }

  const handleAll = () => {
    setFetchData(fetchData);
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleAll}>Show all</button>
      <button onClick={handle1}>Filter by id 1</button>
      <button onClick={handle2}>Filter by id 2</button>
      {renderdata()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: "but for some reason its not working", what isn't working? Any errors?

Comment: `if (fetchData) {`: what are going to return if this condition isn't met?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `id` is a number, not a string, so you filter(s) need to be changed like that:

```
const result1 = fetchData.filter((inner) => inner.id === 1);
```

You have another problem, is that you change the whole data set when you filter, so once you've filtered, you can't "unfilter" or filter again on another id.

You need to maintain the original `fetchedData` unchanged.

This [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4ep7yq?file=src/App.js) shows how it can be fixed.

Comment: I've edited the answer with an example that shows how it can work.

Answer (score 3):

I found 2 issues in your code

1. Id in the API result is numeric not string
   `inner.id === '2'`. so this will return false `inner.id === 2` you need to use like this
2. when you assign the filtered value to the original array it will of course change the original array so when you try to filter it second time you don't have the original API result in the fetch data array because it is already filtered
   So i have created one more array `filteredData`
   This will work.

   ```
   import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
   import axios from 'axios';
   import "./style.css";

   export default function App() {

     const [fetchData, setFetchData] = useState([]);
     const [filteredData, setFileredData] = useState([]);
     const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
     const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

     const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';

     useEffect(() => {
         let mounted = true;
         const loadData = async () => {
             try {
                 const response = await axios(url);
                 if (mounted) {
                     setFetchData(response.data);
                     setFileredData(response.data)
                     setLoading(false);
                     setIsError(false);
                     console.log('data mounted')
                 }
             } catch (err) {
                 setIsError(true)
                 setLoading(false);
                 setFetchData([]);
                 console.log(err);
             }
         };
         loadData();
         return () => {
             mounted = false;
             console.log('cleaned');
         };
     },
         [url]
     );


     const renderdata = () => {
       if (filteredData) {
         return (
           <div>{filteredData.map(inner => {
             return (
               <React.Fragment key={inner.id}>
               <p>{inner.title}</p>
               </React.Fragment>
             )
           })}</div>
         )
       } else {
         <p>No data to display!</p>
       }
     }

     const handle1 = () => {
       const result1 = fetchData.filter((inner) => inner.id === 1);
       setFileredData(result1);
     }

     const handle2 = () => {
       const result2 = fetchData.filter((inner) => inner.id === 2);
       setFileredData(result2);
     }

     const handleAll = () => {
       setFileredData(fetchData);
     }


     return (
       <div>
         <button onClick={handleAll}>Show all</button>
         <button onClick={handle1}>Filter by id 1</button>
         <button onClick={handle2}>Filter by id 2</button>
         {renderdata()}
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks Sojin, I would accept the answer but someone answered before.